# What is the nature of the Key, Value, and InputFormat types passed to Spark's StreamingContext.fileStream[K, V, F]("directory")

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

From what I understand, streaming *text* files from a directory requires a key of type `LongWritable`, a value of `Text`, and a format of `TextInputFormat`. These are passed automatically in the `textFileStream()` method.

Is the key in that case the line number, with the value being the text on that line?

What should the key and value types be for `ParquetInputFormat` - and more generally, how can I figure this out for myself regarding other file types?

Also, how do these types relate to the `DStream` that is returned by the method? If I pass a parquet file which has rows of, say, 100 columns, how will this be parsed into RDDs and DStreams by spark?

Answer (score 0):

For ParquetInputFormat I think the key type must be Void, and the value type an object representing your data.

`ssc.fileStream[Void, YourObject, ParquetInputFormat[YourObject]]("hdfs:...")`